# I had locked my server desktop hard disk D and E with protection of Bit Locker

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, bitlocker

I had locked my server desktop hard disk D and E with protection of Bit Locker using the uniform password for all the drives and the computers.

My computer technician had unplugged from the socket in working condition without logging off and when we logged in again the PC password was accepted but the password for 
Bit Locker was denied and as a result all the disk access were denied even after inserting the correct password.

Kindly suggest a solution as I don't have any back-up for my data  which are years old.

Comment: Buy a new keyboard, your shift key seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

1. fix your Caps Lock or Shift key or finger. You do not write in all caps in public space - it's considered lame, rude and generally speaks about your immaturity.
2. It may be required to plug the drives back in the same machine they were taken out of. This is the feature of TPM module - it may perceive unplugging and plugging back the drive as configuration change, which would lock down BitLocker. If that doesn't help, you need to use recovery key to unlock that drive (but in this instance you do not need same computer).
3. make sure you type in correct password. In other words: see first sentence of #1
4. > Also, always, always, always, always have a backup of data if it is crucially important to you... – Big Chris
5. In case the whole machine was unplugged from power (possible as the question is not clear on that) the issue is if encryption was ongoing or they were encypted long time ago? If the drive encryption was being done when power off then you should be able to continue process after boot, or you may have to use Bitlocker recovery tool. If not, then in all probabilities the bitlocker password you're entering is incorrect. You should try bitlocker recovery key.

Comment: Also, always, always, always, always have a backup of data if it is crucially important to you...